# ipython notebook on android

Tags: python

im trying to run ipython notbook on my android. Followed this link: http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-7-2013/general/ipython-jupyter-notebook-android-t3037226
it worked fine but the kernel is dying all the time. Dont believe its ok. I did not root the device.
I am not even a newbie in android, so my question is: 
Is this normal or someone has an idea what to do ?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/49837474/321973